# Button click event doesn't work properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, events

This following code handle button click event. When the user click first time it sets the lable as "First Time", and when the user click second time it sets the lable as "Second Time". But it doesn't work properly. When I first click it, it sets the lable as "First time", which is correct, but when I click second time, nothing happend.

My code:

```
int counter=0;    
protected void btnCompTagUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (counter == 0)
    {
        lable1.Text="First Time";
        counter++;
    }
    else if (counter == 1)
    {
        lable1.Text="Second Time";
        counter--;
    }

    }
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: you spelled counter wrong: Coutner ;)

Comment: Due the web-development tag is this ASP.NET?

Comment: you declared `Coutner` and use  `counter` HOW?

Comment: You may have just mistyped it, but you declare "counter" as "Coutner"

Comment: Your `counter` variable does not survive postbacks (it will always be reset to `0` on every page load). You can persist it in the page's view state, or in the user's session, depending on your requirements.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi How can I enable view state for a variable? can u tell me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The values of instance fields like `counter` are not saved across postbacks. You need to store `counter` in `ViewState`, `Session`, or some other persistent store, whichever is more appropriate. For example:

```
private int Counter
{
    get { return ((int?)this.ViewState["Counter"]).GetValueOrDefault(); }
    set { this.ViewState["Counter"] = value; }
}
```

Then reference `this.Counter` instead of `counter` in `btnCompTagUpdate_Click`.

Comment: Thanks for your help it worked. Just wondering what is the method GetValueOrDefault()? what it does?

Comment: The expression `(int?)this.ViewState["Counter"]` evaluates to a `Nullable<int>` whose value is either null (if `Counter` was never set) or an integer. The `Nullable<int>.GetValueOrDefault()` method returns 0 if the value is null; otherwise, it just returns the integer.

Answer (score 6):

If "Coutner" is initialized exactly in the way you are listing, then that's your problem. Coutner gets re-initialized to zero after every postback. You need to save Coutner's state -- I normally recommend against it for any but the simplest cases, but I think you have a valid case for the use of [ViewState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

```
void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   if (!IsPostBack)
     Session["counter"]=0;
 }
```

You set the counter value at once, when first the page loads.

```
protected void btnCompTagUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 int counter=0;
if (Session["counter"]!=null)
 counter= Convert.ToInt32(Session["counter"]);
  if (counter == 0)
  {
    lable1.Text="First Time";
    counter++;
   Session["counter"]=counter;
  }
 else if (counter == 1)
  {
    lable1.Text="Second Time";
    counter--;
   Session["counter"]=counter;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is that the counter variable is not persisting its value between postbacks. Each time the button is clicked, the counter variable is reset to 0. To fix this issue, you need to persist the counter variable across postbacks, for example, by using session state. Here's how you can modify your code to achieve the desired functionality:
Code :

```html
@{
    int counter = (Session["Counter"] == null) ? 0 : (int)Session["Counter"];
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Button Click Counter</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <label id="label1">@ViewBag.LabelText</label>
            <br />
            <button id="btnCompTagUpdate" type="submit" runat="server" onclick="btnCompTagUpdate_Click">Click Me</button>
        </div>
    </form>

    @if (IsPostBack)
    {
        if (counter == 0)
        {
            ViewBag.LabelText = "First Time";
            counter++;
        }
        else if (counter == 1)
        {
            ViewBag.LabelText = "Second Time";
            counter--;
        }

        Session["Counter"] = counter;
    }
</body>
</html>
```

By using session state, the value of the counter variable will persist across postbacks, allowing your code to function correctly.

[kountif.com](https://kountif.com/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -4):

You only need to change the way you increase the counter in the method. You are not saving it back as a new variable after the button click.

```
int counter = 0;     
protected void btnCompTagUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {     
if (counter == 0)     { 
counter = counter + 1;        
label1.Text="First Time";             
}    
 else if (counter == 1) {         
counter = counter - 1;        
label1.Text="Second Time";   
 }     
 }
```

Comment: Int.equals is identical to == for integers, same thing for the x++ and x= x+1