# Increment number per button click C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, increment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Button click event doesn't work properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280299/button-click-event-doesnt-work-properly)

I try to increment an int for each click on a default page. `Int=0`. It only goes up to 1. What should I do to increment the number for each click?

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private int speed = 0;

    public int Speed
    {
        get { return speed; }  // Getter
        set { speed = value; } // Setter
    }

    public void accelerate()
    {
        //speed++;
        this.Speed = this.Speed + 1;
    }

    public void decelerate()
    {
        // speed--;
        this.Speed = this.Speed - 1;
    }

    public int showspeed()
    {
        return this.Speed;
    }

    //car bmw = new car();
    public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //datatype objectname = new

       dashboard.Text = Convert.ToString(this.showspeed());
    }

    public void acc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       this.accelerate();
       dashboard.Text = Convert.ToString(this.showspeed());
    }

    public void dec_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.decelerate();
        this.showspeed();
    }
}
```

Comment: A inconfutable proof of the stateless nature of the web

Comment: Seems to be the same problem as described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9968298/visual-studios-c-sharp-class-re-called-on-page-refresh

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [ViewState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx) to maintain the value across postbacks:

```
private int Speed
{
   get
   {
       if (ViewState["Speed"] == null)
           ViewState["Speed"] = 0;
       return (int)ViewState["Speed"];
   }
   set { ViewState["Speed"] = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the result in a way that will persist over postback.  I suggest using ViewState, for example:

```
public int Speed
{
    get { 
        if(ViewState["Speed"] == null) {
             ViewState["Speed"] = 1;
        }
        return Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["Speed"]);
     }

    set { 
         ViewState["Speed"] = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think is better for speed to start from 0

Answer (score 1):

Because everytime when you click on the button, it is initializing the value of speed to 0.

**HTTP is stateless**. That means it wil not retain the values of variable across your postback like you do in [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) programming. So you need to keep the value across your postbacks.

You can use a hidden element in your page to store the value and access the value every time you want to do a function on that:

```
 <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnFileId" runat="server" Value="" />
```

and in your page load, you can read the value and load it to your variable.

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.speed = ConvertTo.Int32(hdnFileId.Value);
}
```

From [Adrianftode's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/782754/adrian-iftode) comment, the data for the controls like TextBox, Checkbox, Radio button controls values will be posted to the server on the postback because they are rendered as standard HTML form controls in the browser. See *[Chapter 4. Working with ASP.NET Server Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg615475%28v=vs.88%29.aspx)*.

Comment: The value of an input doesn't need to be maintained through viewstate. Why should be, if it is passes back and forth each time?

Comment: @AdrianIftode: Since hTTP is stateless. the value in the typical input field will not be available on post back. All ASP.NET controls uses ViewState internally to keep the values during postback

Comment: I'm sure this statement is not valid for inputs, I explained why

Comment: @AdrianIftode: In this cas the OP wants to get the previously updated value on each button click event to update it again. For hidden controls, asp.net use viewstate internally to keep the value. i believe the (previously saved)value should be available in the button click event

Comment: http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article760-common-misconception-regarding-viewstate-and-textbox.aspx

Comment: @AdrianIftode : Can u pls tell which statement is wrong in my answer.  I could not understand your point properly

Comment: "The hidden field value will be retained across postbacks using a mechanism called "ViewState" offered by ASP.NET." - this is false. ASP .Net sets the value of a TextBox, HiddenField, Button from the posted values (from the HTTP POST header). So it doesn't need to use ViewState, it would be a "double" storage

Comment: Those values are submitted each time to the server..

Comment: @AdrianIftode: I got your point.You are absolutely correct.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg615475(v=vs.88).aspx. I will update my answer. This is something i learned today. Thank you very much.

Comment: @AdrianIftode: I updated my answer with your point.