# Asp.net MVC Increment Button

Tags: asp.net-mvc, button, increment

In Asp.Net MVC I want to increment a model property on every form submission (button click).

I've tried both HttpGet and HttpPost. With HttpGet, the value is always overridden by the querystring and it's always 0. With HttpPost, the value starts as 0, I click the button and it increments to 1. But any more times I click it, it comes in as 0 and increments to 1.

From what I understand, it Inputs 0, 0+1 = 1, Outputs 0

To make it simple:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.Value) or @Html.Hidden("Value", Model.Value)
    or even <input type="hidden" value="@Model.Value" />
    <input type="submit" value="Click Me" />
}

public ViewResult ActionMethod(Model model)
{
    model.Value++;
    return View(model);
}
```

My question is basically this:
[Increment number per button click C# ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9968488/increment-number-per-button-click-c-sharp-asp-net)
but in the MVC framework.

How do you manipulate model properties like this? I don't wish to use Javascript.

Comment: Believe it or not, I'd go as far as to say JQuery was probably your best solution for this. It's just something very simple that can be done client side without much hassle at all

Comment: Your updated solution is the only way to do it.  MVC will use the posted values to update your view, so you have to clear them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I've been told, this is the only solution:

I found this to work, but it's really awful

```
int temp = ++model.Value;
ModelState.Remove("Value");
model.Value = temp;
```

If I pass a model parameter to the view, the view should bind that parameter by taking whatever I pass in the model's current state.

Answer (score -2):

You have to call

```
UpdateModel(model);
```

IIRC.

Comment: ASP.NET MVC doesnt have that.

Comment: I was hoping it would be that easy, but I can't make it do anything different. Is there a certain time you have to call that? From what I've read, UpdateModel is for binding the model in the controller. From my observation, that part is fine. It's the View that isn't updating.

Comment: I don't have the time to make a working example but IIRC:  

Call UpdateModel(model) when you are finished with your update.  Then call return View(model) just like you did.

Stab in the dark: Try model.Value += 1; or model.Value = model.Value + 1;  

Also: Use Fiddler for checking what goes in an out of you web server.